# Reuse same database object when doing multiple lookups - Django

Tags: python, database, django, caching, foreign-keys

This question involves caching/optimisation/reducing calls to the database in Django

My (hypothetical) scenario is that I'm pulling a list of addresses from a server, which changes every so often.

Now the postcode may well be common between some of the addresses.
I already have a list of postcodes in my database, for which the model looks something like:

```
class PostCode(models.Model);
     postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     name_of_postman = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

For each address, I need to create a new 'address' object, and store that in the database, which requires me to lookup the postcode (which is a foreign key)

```
class Address(models.Model):
     address_line1 = models.CharField(...)
     ...
     postcode = models.ForeignKey(PostCode, related_name='+')
```

Now, whilst iterating over my addresses obtained from the server, I'm finding I have to do something like:

```
for address in all_addresses:
   ...
   if address.is_useful():
       Address.objects.create(address_line1=line1, postcode=Postcode.objects.get(postcode=postcode))
```

As you can see, I'm retrieving the postcode every time I save an address, which isn't very optimal if I've already retrieved that postcode whilst saving a different address.
What I'd like to do is optimise this so that if the same postcode is used 100 times for different addresses, I'm not having to retrieve the same stuff from the database 100 times.

(I don't want to pre-populate a list of all the postcodes, since I might not need them all (see the `address.is_useful()` line)

My current ideas have been:

create a dict and store already-getted objects in that. Something like:

```
postcodes = {}
for address in all_addresses:
   ...
   if address.is_useful():
        Address.objects.create(address_line1=line1, postcode=postcodes.setdefault(postcode, Postcode.objects.get(postcode=postcode)))
```

this brings me to the question of database caching. Is this effectively what database caching acheives (albeit in a slightly more complex way)? If so, I guess I may as well just use database caching.

---

UPDATE:

My `setdefault()` solution won't work, since the `default` value, whatever it is, is processed every time irrespective of if it's used:

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> def val():
...     print 'running the val() function'
...     return 1
...
>>>
>>> dict.setdefault('key', val())
running the val() function
1
>>> dict.setdefault('key', val())
running the val() function
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you extract the postcode before going into the for loop?

```
postcode_obj = Postcode.objects.get(postcode=postcode)
for address in all_addresses:
...
    Address.objects.create(address_line1=line1, postcode=postcode_obj)
```

That way you have 1 query for the postcode.

Comment: 2 reasons: because it requires an extra for-loop to iterate of all the addresses, and more importantly, based on some logic to do with what the address actually is, I might not need to store it. I've updated my question

Comment: Same goes with this scenario. Getting a single postcode object from the database is cheap. If you cache it, you still have to get it. This way, it's already in memory.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't really follow. Anyway, 'getting a single postcode from the database is cheap' is a bit of a sweeping statement. It's not cheap when: your postcode table contains 1000s of entries, and also when memory is expensive :/

Comment: As I said, you still need to get it to cash it. Just get it once. Django evaluates queries lazy. The query will be executed when needed. If memory is expensive, you need to use different approach (caching it to disk/redis/etc) but you still need to make the initial query. And yes. Getting a single row by index from a table containing 1000 even 1.000.000 of rows is cheap.